# Appending quantity of shopping cart with JS and DRF

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get my API to work on the front end of my django app, I have got to the point at which it successfully creates a new cart and adds the initial item to it, but once the button is clicked again it creates a brand new cart. I am getting zero errors so I think this is just down to lack of knowledge, any guidance and advice would be great.

```
   <script>

        const updateBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.update-cart');
        const user = '{{request.user}}';
        for(let i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
            updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent page from refreshing
                const productId = this.dataset.product;
                const action = this.dataset.action;
                console.log('productId:', productId, 'action:', action);
                console.log('USER:', user);
                createCart(productId, action);
                addCartItem(productId, action);
            });
        }
        function addCartItem(productId, action){
        
            if(action === 'add'){
                if(cart[productId] === undefined){
                    cart[productId] = {'quantity':1};
                }else{
                    cart[productId]['quantity'] += 1;
                }
            }
        
            if(action === 'remove'){
                cart[productId]['quantity'] -= 1;
        
                if(cart[productId]['quantity'] <= 0){
                    console.log('Remove Item');
                    delete cart[productId];
        
                }
            }
            console.log('Cart:', cart);
            document.cookie = `cart=${JSON.stringify(cart)};domain=;path=/`;
            location.reload();
        } 

        function createCart(productId, action){
            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
            console.log('User is logged in, sending data...');
        
            const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/carts/`;
        
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                },
                body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action}),
                mode: 'same-origin',
            })
                .then((response) =>{
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then((data) =>{
                    console.log('CartDATA', data);
                    const cartId = data.id;
                    console.log('CartId', cartId)

                    
                    const cartItemUrl = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/carts/${cartId}/items/`;
                    fetch(cartItemUrl, {
                      method: 'POST',
                      headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify({
                        'product_id': productId,
                        'quantity': 1
                      }),
                      mode: 'same-origin',
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                      return response.json();
                    })
                    .then((data) => {
                      console.log('CartItem', data);
                    });
                });
              }
    
        
    </script>


class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)
    items = CartItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total_price(self, cart):
        return sum([item.quantity * item.product.price for item in cart.items.all()])

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'items', 'total_price']
    
class AddCartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    def validate_product_id(self, value):
        if not Product.objects.filter(pk=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('No product with the given ID was found.')
        return value

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        cart_id = self.context['cart_id']
        product_id = self.validated_data['product_id']
        quantity = self.validated_data['quantity']

        try: 
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(cart_id=cart_id, product_id=product_id)
            cart_item.quantity += quantity
            cart_item.save()
            self.instance = cart_item
        except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
            self.instance = CartItem.objects.create(cart_id=cart_id, **self.validated_data)
        
        return self.instance

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['id', 'product_id', 'quantity']

class UpdateCartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['quantity']

class CartViewSet(CreateModelMixin,
                  RetrieveModelMixin,
                  DestroyModelMixin,
                  GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Cart.objects.prefetch_related('items__product').all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer

class CartItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']
   
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return AddCartItemSerializer
        elif self.request.method == 'PATCH':
            return UpdateCartItemSerializer
        return CartItemSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'cart_id': self.kwargs['cart_pk']}

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CartItem.objects \
                .filter(cart_id=self.kwargs['cart_pk']) \
                .select_related('product')
```

Comment: I don't see any jQuery used.

Comment: You are calling `createCart` every time an update button is clicked. I assume this creates a new cart.

Comment: Well I thought my code would create one if an item was already in the cart, instead it would append

Comment: It's not clear to me that the a new cart does not get created on every click. I don't see any conditional logic for this in the code you have provided. Maybe the API contains this logic? Does the same Cart ID get returned by subsequent requests to `/api/carts/`?

Comment: Hi, I have added my serializers and viewsets relating to the cart, maybe these can help you shed some light onto it for me? Like I say I am relatively new to this side of things so just trying to learn

Comment: I can't look into all of the Django Rest Framework code, but I can tell you that `POST` requests in REST are for creating new objects. So the fact that your front-end calls `createCart` with every update click look problematic to me. You might want to try making this call once and then caching the result, so that requests to update items can use the cached cart ID.

Comment: This helped me more than you know! Thank you, I have not got to the point where no new cart is existed and adds new items to cart but now i need to fix quantity.

Comment: Maybe this example code can be of help to you: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/vjp4qonk/

Comment: Brilliant! Quick question  you've already helped enough so don't worry if you cannot answer. Should I be using views along side my api views for functionality, for example a view to render the cart items , quantity and totals etc or should my apiviewsets and serializers be handling all of this.

Comment: I am not familiar with Django REST Framework and what "views" means to it, so I am lacking some context here. However, I would say that if you are going with a REST API (as opposed to something like an MVC (Model, View, Controller) framework) then the frontend and backend should be separate and you don't want rendering logic bundled into your API code.